# How can I upload a .eps file?

Tags: 7, files, media

I added an image field to my user on this page admin/config/people and marked the allowed file extensions to be `eps`, `png`, `jpg`.  However, it doesn't allow me to upload `.eps` file, but only `.png` and `.jpg`.

I get this message:

> The specified file gold coins elements vector5.eps could not be uploaded. Only files with the following extensions are allowed: `jpg jpeg gif png txt doc xls pdf ppt pps odt ods odp`.

How can I upload an `.eps` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to change the field type to "file" , and then I can add eps files

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure EPS files can't be displayed in browsers, which may be why you're having a problem. There's a module which will allow for EPS files to be converted on upload, which may solve your particular issue:

https://www.drupal.org/project/imagefield_eps

Comment: its not that I want it displayed.  its that it won't let me upload it .  so that module wont help me

Comment: Sorry. Perhaps you could use the core upload field or CCK Filefield module instead of imagefield?